# Can't enter value  when use keyChar() override method

Tags: java, blackberry

I've show webpage using browserfield. It showing fine.

I override the keyChar() method for scroll the page when hit the spacebar. its also working fine.

```
protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) 
    {       
        if(c == Keypad.KEY_SPACE)
        {

           listContainer.setVerticalScroll();

         }
    }

    return true;
}
```

My problem is, when i show this page http://special.belo.com/wcnc/mobile/ad_form/ i can't enter text in that textbox.  The keyChar() override method not allow to enter the text on text filed.

Pls help me. How to enter the text on page which is shown on browserfield.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're capturing all keys but handle only space. The usual pattern is to call the super method when you're done with your work:

```
protected boolean keyChar(char c, int status, int time) {       
    if(c == Keypad.KEY_SPACE) {
           listContainer.setVerticalScroll();
    }
    return super.keyChar(c, status, time);
}
```

Comment: Its working fine. But when i press backspace key, its throws illegal state expression. Its show only on balckebrry simulator.

Comment: The backspace key is handled by the super method and maybe it is not allowed in the actual context. Try to find out *where* it occurs, try to get a stacktrace and it may be worth another question on SO! It is not thrown in *this* method.